# Changing output format of list when using GSON

Tags: java, arraylist, gson

I have an `ArrayList` of pojo's that I would like to convert to `JSON`, currently when I call `Gson.toJson(list)` it returns a string:

```
[
  {
    "key1": "value1", 
    "key2": "value2",
    "key3": "value3"
  },
  {
    "key1": "value1", 
    "key2": "value2",
    "key3": "value3"
  }
]
```

But I would like to return the `JSON` as a list of objects not in an array such as:

```
  {
    "key1": "value1", 
    "key2": "value2",
    "key3": "value3"
  },
  {
    "key1": "value1", 
    "key2": "value2",
    "key3": "value3"
  }
```

Is there a way to achieve this directly, or should I just alter the output string?

Comment: Please, don't change it. The one that you have is a valid json (an array of objects), the one that you are asking for is not. https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: The only way to put a list of anything in JSON is in an array.  Your modified version is not valid JSON.

Comment: The reason I'm asking is that if its in the second form without the `[]` i can directly read the file as separate objects (rows in a table) in AWS Athena without having to do anything extra, whereas (i think) if it is in the array Athena displays it as a single object that contains an array

Comment: Hi, if my answer is the solution to your problem please mark it accordingly. If not, please specify what issue still exists. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be to use java 8 streams (which can be translated to non-stream version, of course):

```
List<Pojo> values = new ArrayList<>();
values.add(new Pojo("value1.1", "value1.2"));
values.add(new Pojo("value2.1", "value2.2"));

String desiredOutput = values
        .stream()
        .map(pojoItem -> new Gson().toJson(pojoItem))
        .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

which produces

```
{"key1":"value1.1","key2":"value1.2"},{"key1":"value2.1","key2":"value2.2"}
```

The code

1. first iterates over your list (`values.stream()`)
2. transforms every item of it into its json-representation (`.map(pojoItem -> new Gson().toJson(pojoItem)`). So now you virtually have a list of json-strings
3. The items of this virtual list are concatenated by a comma and returned as a String (`.collect(Collectors.joining(",")`).

Of course you can adjust it to your needs, for example to not join with a comma but with a line break to get [JSON Lines format](http://jsonlines.org/examples/).